# Can someone clear up my question on an area under the curve.

Tags: calculus, area, curves

Find the area under the curve $y=2x^{−3}$ 
from $x=9$  to  $x=t$ and evaluate it for $t=10$,  $t=100$. 
Then find the total area under this curve for $x \geq 9$.

I found the first two answers, but I am having trouble with the third one. 
For $t=10$, area = $0.00234568$;
for $t=100$, area = $0.0122476$.
But how do I find the total area?

Comment: That would depend on how you found it for $t=10$ and for $t=100$. Did you not evaluate a definite integral? Do you know about improper integrals as limits?

Comment: $$\int_9^\infty 2x^{-3} \; dx=-\frac1{x^2}\Biggr|_{x=9}^{x=\infty}=0+\frac1{4(81)}$$

Comment: The expression in $t$ will converge to some number if $t$ becomes large.

Comment: Take the upper limit as $ \infty $

Comment: Okay great! Thank you! I ended up with 1/81. Is the upper limit infinity because x = any number greater than 9?

Comment: Yes, you could say so. $\frac{1}{81}$ is the correct answer.

Comment: @drhab, I believe your comment is intended for Shahar.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Indeed. Apologies for that.

Comment: @drhab I have no idea where that 4 came from. My bad o_o I'm typing on my phone and there's no SE app.

Comment: @Shahar At first there were two $4$-s. Also $\frac{1}{4x^{2}}$ instead of $\frac{1}{x^{2}}$. You noticed that
mistake and repaired the comment. But only one of the $4$-s was removed.

Comment: @drhab Oh right, just remembered that I wrote that. Dang.